# UIImagePicker Shows blank when application in landscape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using navigation based application here when i call `UIImagePicker` then it show blank when the screen is in landscape but this shows correctly when the screen in portrait.

How can i change screen to portrait when its in landscape.

I using the code to call photo album is

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];  
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;  
picker.delegate = self;  
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

**Edited:**

Actually i am using TabBarController Which was pushed from another view using the concept of navigationController then when i tried to call `UIImagePickerController` when it is in landscape then shows blank.
  But without TabBarController `UIImagePickerController` works perfect(Automatically rotate to portrait)..

So how could i call UIImagePickerController when in landscape in TabBarController.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If this happens in a UIViewController then do the following so that the view is never rotated:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return NO;
}
```

Comment: Here i want orientation also.Is there any way to rotate screen to portrait when screen in landscape.

Answer (score 0):

if u want to forcefully rotate in portrait use

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{


 return (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait||UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)


}
```

Comment: Ok..But this method is not calling in navigation based application what can i doo..

Comment: yes, self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller : method didn't work even in my case
So i tried :

yourViewController*vc=[[yourViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController*navC=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];

[self presentModalViewController:navC animated:YES];


which worked and was pushed to the next view

Answer (score 0):

`UIImagePickerController` is portrait-only, see the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html):

> **Important:** The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait
>   mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified [...]